# WordPress: Embed JavaScript in post content not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to place a JavaScript code to my WordPress post but nothing displayed:

[image: Screenshot of post edit screen]

I'm using the custom fields method using the **Code Embed** plugin.

The JavaScript is taken from this [link](http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-google:compute-asia-east1) and here's the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function ch_st_loaded(speedtest) {speedtest.start();}</script><script async type="text/javascript" src="//cloudharmony.com/rum/speedtest-google:compute-asia-east1.js"></script>
```

[image: screenshot of code in post edit screen]

Am I implementing this correctly? Appreciate if someone can correct me or provide alternative. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested the **Embed Code** plugin with the given JS. The shortcode is added to the page properly, so its not a plugin issue. But nothing is displayed on the page. Try checking if the JS code is correct.

Comment: @veesar I'm pretty sure that is the correct JS code. You can refer to this link: http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-google:compute-asia-east1. Maybe the JS code need some modification when implementing in WP? Appreciate your insight